# question from exam: prove the matrix is Invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $d\ge2$, $d$ is an integer, $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix of integers with each divisible by $d$--that is, each $a_{ij} = 0 \pmod d.$
Prove $I + A$ is an invertible matrix.

I tried thinking about the determinant but doesn't seem very helpful..

Answer (score 6):

Try thinking about the determinant some more. Specifically, think about $\det (I+A)$ modulo $d$. If you prove that $\det(I+A) \not \equiv 0 \mod d$, then it will follow that $\det(I+A) \neq 0$.

Comment: Excellent hint. +1

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'm trying it right now, i took the d out of the determinant of I+A, i mean: d*| | and have of course 1/d where the 1s of the I , so it starts to make sense but Im stuck. can you give me another hint how to continue?

Comment: @user84636 Here is a hint: derive from the determinant formula that $\det X \equiv \det Y \mod d$ if each entry of $X$ is congruent to the corresponding entry of $Y$ modulo $d$.

Comment: @user84636 Then put $X=I$ and $Y=I+A$. You'll get $\det (I+A) \equiv 1 \mod d$, and this will be it.

Comment: By determinant formula here I mean the [Leibniz formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants), although of course this is not the only way.

Comment: how did you get det(I+A)≡1 ?

Comment: Because, $\det(I+A)\equiv \det I$, and $\det I = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove the statement *without* using determinant. Suppose $I+A$ is non-invertible. As it is an integer matrix, $(I+A)x=0$ has a nontrivial *integer* solution (to see this, think about the reduced echelon form of $I+A$). By pulling out common factors of the entries of $x$, we may assume further that the GCD of the entries of $x$ is $1$. Explain why this contradicts $(I+A)x\equiv0\mod d$.